# convert string to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I have a Date format in excel like "20.03.2013" i transformed that to "2013-03-20" since this is how the dates look like in my sql-server table. I created a staging table where i gave that field the varchar(15) datatype. now i have to convert that varchar field to a date field but when i check the list of the convert options i cannot find yyy-mmm-dd. [HERE](http://www.itrain.de/knowhow/sql/tsql/datum/datumconvert.asp) Need help to get my yyyy-mm-dd string to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use:

`CAST('2013-03-20' AS DATE)` to convert it to a `DATE` field.

There are a number of formats that will CAST() as DATE without issue, including:

```
20130320
2013-03-20
2013 mar 20
March 20, 2013
2013.03.20
```

I'm sure there's a comprehensive list somewhere, but couldn't find one with a quick search.  I believe language settings can affect some of them.

Comment: Greate this works fine for me and i learned something very useful. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

[check here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Syntax for CAST:

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type [ (length ) ])
```

Syntax for CONVERT:

```
CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this format will cast automatically in any region, so:

```
select cast('2013-03-20' as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use explicit `convert` instead of `cast`:

```
select convert(date, '2013-03-20', 120)
```

Comment: why would you use convert over cast?

Comment: first of all - you don't have to think about what formats SQL will reads automatically, and it's easier to read in code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also try out this 
`convert(nvarchar(200), GETDATE(), 112)` 
for 20200611 format